# Regular Expression: Capture Negation of Combination of Multiple Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group

I have a large regex combined from smaller regexes that I am trying to take the negation of in order to capture characters not in the regex (such as ~, `, @, #, $, %, ^, &).

I tried writing a regular expression for my error case, but nothing is being found. Perhaps this is because of the order of the regexes? Additionally, "!=" is considered a special symbol whereas "!" is considered an error. I tried to use negative-lookahead to account for this (to no avail).

```
...
String keyword = "\\b(?:else|if|int|return|void|while)\\b";
String identifier = "\\b[a-zA-Z]+\\b";
String number = "\\b[\\d]+\\b";
String special_symbol = "(==)|(!=)|(<=)|(>=)|(\\+)|(\\-)|(\\*)|(\\/)|(\\<)|(\\>)|(\\=)|(\\;)|(\\,)|(\\()|(\\))|(\\[)|(\\])|(\\{)|(\\})|(\\,)";
String error = "[_`~@#$%^&]|(!(?!(=)))";
String regex = "(" + keyword + ")|(" + identifier + ")|(" + number + ")|(" + special_symbol + ")|(" + error + ")";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

for( Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str); matcher.find(); ) {
   if ( matcher.start(1) != -1 ) {
      System.out.println("Keyword: " + matcher.group() );
   } else if ( matcher.start(2) != -1 ) {
      System.out.println("ID: " + matcher.group() );
   } else if ( matcher.start(3) != -1 ) {
      System.out.println("NUM: " + matcher.group());
   } else if ( matcher.start(4) != -1 ) {
      System.out.println( matcher.group() );
   } else if ( matcher.start(5) != -1 ) {
      System.out.println("ERROR: " + matcher.group() );
   }
} // for
...

Expected Output:
INPUT: iiii = 3@33;
ID: iiii 
=
NUM: 3
Error: @33
;

Actual Output:
INPUT: iiii = 3@33;
ID: iiii
=
NUM: 3
NUM: 33
;

Expected Output:
INPUT: else ret_urn gcd(vxxxxxxvvvvv, u-u/v*v);
keyword: else
ID: ret
Error: _urn
ID: gcd
(
ID: vxxxxxxvvvvv
,
ID: u
-
ID: u
/
ID: v
*
ID: v
)
;

Actual Output:
INPUT: else ret_urn gcd(vxxxxxxvvvvv, u-u/v*v);
Keyword: else
ID: gcd
(
ID: vxxxxxxvvvvv
,
ID: u
-
ID: u
/
ID: v
*
ID: v
)
;

Expected Output:
INPUT: !
Error: !

Actual Output:
INPUT: !
(This is supposed to be an error, but nothing is captured)
```

Comment: It would be nice to actually see some input with pass or fail. Even a regex output since Java is not on my machine to run.

Comment: @sln everything past the "..." are input examples. Do you need more input examples?

Comment: What did you expect `(!(?!(=)))` to do? A `!` that is not followed by `=`? Why? The `!` (NOT) operator should be a valid "special_symbol", shouldn't it? --- Regardless, it's overly long with those two unnecessary capture groups, so just use `!(?!=)`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier for `error` to just grab an single non-whitespace character that isn't already matched by the earlier expressions? As in `error = "\\S"`

Comment: Wow. I had no idea capture groups would cause this many issues, I'll be sure to use them minimally next time. Also, yes. "\\S+" is the error and the rest of the token. Much appreciated! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyword`, `identifier`, and `number` don't define any capture groups, so `regex` defines `keyword` as group 1, `identifier` as group 2, `number` as group 3, and `special_symbol` as group 4.

*However*, since `special_symbol` defines many capture groups, group 5 is `(==)`. It is not the 5th `()` in `regex`. Since there are 20 capture groups in `special_symbol`, it means that `error` is group 25, but don't use that (too error prone with future changes).

Remove all capture groups from `special_symbol`:

```
String special_symbol = "==|!=|<=|>=|\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/|\\<|\\>|\\=|\\;|\\,|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]|\\{|\\)|\\,";
```

Oh, and oops, you have both `\\,` and `\\)` in there twice, and no `\\}`.

Besides, all those single special characters should be in a character class, not in a big OR sequence:

```
String special_symbol = "==|!=|<=|>=|[+\\-*/<>=;,()\\[\\]{}]";
```